# Macromedia Fireworks 6.0

Tags: fireworks

I understand this is an old technology, but I have been using it forever and own the software so I can't really change. I just installed Fireworks 6.0 on a Windows 7 box and even thought I can use the keyboard to get to my tools I can't actually CLICK any of my tools. It is the strangest thing I have ever seen. Could this be a Windows 7 issue because I've installed this product countless times on Windows XP machines and I can't ever remember this happening....HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with using Fireworks 6 ended up being even more bizarre than I originally thought. On my new laptop running Windows 7 I can not click to anything in my toolbox HOWEVER when I put Fireworks on my second monitor I can click everything in my toolbox. I found this out quite by accident.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with old fireworks on windows 7 where it would not save preferences, one of the fixes was to enable compatibility mode and set it to run as administrator, you can do this by right clicking on the fireworks icon.

Hope that helps this problem too.